# How to write a valid JSON Schema for a document with only optional elements

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I use JSON Schema to validate YAML and JSON configuration files. In one configuration file are all elements optional. But only is a limited set of elements is allowed.

What do I have to change in the given schema below, so that an empty file/document in case of JSON is also valid?

```json
{
  "$id": "https://snafu.com/api/service/publishing-mechanism/config-delta/1.0.0",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "description": "....",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "plans": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "minProperties": 1,
      "patternProperties": {
        "^.*$": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "validation": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["auto", "manual"]
            },
            "security": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["api_key"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there's some confusion. That schema shows that all the properties ARE optional. They are optional by default. It would need to specify they are required using the `required` keyword for them not to be optional. See https://jsonschema.dev/s/LQsqC (Running in draft-07, but there's nothing incompatible with it in this schema)

Comment: I found the real reason, why the schema is not working for me. I use Jackson to process JSON and YAML. In case of reading an empty YAML document, the root node of the parse result is an instance of `MissingNode`, while an empty JSON dockument (`{}`) has as root node an instance of `ObjectNode`. 

I changed my validator implementation. It no replaces and intance of `MissingNode` with an instance of `ObjectNode`. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after quite some time, here is the solution which is working for my project in production.

```json
{
  "$id": "https://snafu.com/api/service/publishing-mechanism/config-delta/1.0.0",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "description": "....",
  "$defs": {
    "empty": {"type": "null"}
  },
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "plans": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "patternProperties": {
            "^.+$": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": false,
                  "properties": {
                    "description": {
                      "minLength": 1,
                      "type": "string"                  
                    },
                    "security": {
                      "enum": ["api_key"],
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                { "$ref": "#/$defs/empty" }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { "$ref": "#/$defs/empty" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here I use `oneOf` to have two mutually exclusive subschemas. One of the is all the possible properties, where one of them is required.

The second subschema has `null` as type. Therefore the only acceptable value for this schema is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your `patternProperties` and just collapse that into `additionalProperties` -- which takes a schema, not just true/false. Because the `patternProperties` is a wildcard that matches everything, the `additionalProperties` there adds no value.

Otherwise, aside from the `"minProperties": 1` which states that there cannot be *zero* properties, your definition already allows for optional properties at the top level, and at the "plans" level, all properties are optional as well. Use the `required` keyword to ensure that a property is actually present:

Reference: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html